# Does a language have a regular expression if and only if it is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I know that if a language has a regular expression it is regular, is the other way also true?

Comment: Since this is general reference knowledge (available in any textbook and even Wikipedia) to the point of being true by definition, it is unclear what your question is. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a language can be described as a (pure vanilla) regular expression if and only if it is regular. You can see the proof in any decent textbook on formal languages.